how to pass 'setSomeState' to children
I'm trying to build an app with a chat block that does not refresh on page change. The child pages contain prompts to save the user from typing common responses. All my pages live within a /board directory that has a top level page called ‘BoardContainer,tsx’:
'use client'
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import ChatBlock from '../components/ChatBlock/ChatBlock';
import AboutPage from '../dashboard/about/background/page';

interface BoardContainerProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const BoardContainer: React.FC<BoardContainerProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [selectedPrompt, setSelectedPrompt] = useState('');
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const sendPrompt = (prompt: string) => {
    setSelectedPrompt(prompt);
  }

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    console.dir(child);
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child as ReactElement<any>, { sendPrompt });
    }
    console.dir(child);
    return child;
  });

  console.dir(pathname);

  return (
    <>
      <>
        { pathname === '/board/about' ?  <AboutPage sendPrompt={sendPrompt} /> : <PageContent sendPrompt={sendPrompt} /> }
        {/* This works but not suitable for more than 2 child pages */}

        {/* childrenWithProps */}
        {/* this doesn't work either */}

        {/* children */}
      <>

      <>
        <ChatBlock
          prompt={selectedPrompt}
        />
      </>
    </>
  )
}

export default BoardContainer;

I figured a work-around using usePathname and essentially hard coding the child value and passing the sendPrompt function, but this is cumbersome.
I tried using React.cloneElement, but I'm either using this incorrectly or misunderstanding something. How can I pass the sendPrompt function via { children }?

You'll use a callback function...
<ChatBlock prompt={selectedPrompt} setSelectedPrompt={setSelectedPrompt} />
Then for the prop in chat block component itself...
setSelectedPrompt: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
Then for the place you're using it in your chat block code...
onClick={() => setSelectedPrompt('prompt1')}

I want to pass setSelectedPrompt to { children } not 
